# How plot polyfit `n log n` with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Below is an excerpt of my code that plots and creates a trend line based of the order that is given to the `numpy.polyfit` library. I'm able to plot linear, quadratic, and many other polynomial trends. However I'm not able to create trend lines for data that might fit [image: log n] or [image: n log n] trends.

Any hits how to go about doing this?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot, pylab

def plotChart(title, xlabel, ylabel, x, y, fit):
    plot1 = pyplot.plot(x, y, "o", label="runtime")
    plot2 = pyplot.plot(x, fit(x), "--", label="trendline")
    pylab.title(title)
    pylab.ylabel(ylabel)
    pylab.xlabel(xlabel)
    pyplot.legend()
    pyplot.tight_layout()
    pyplot.show()

def analyzeTimes(sampleList, timingList, order, title, xlabel, ylabel):
    x = np.array(sampleList)
    y = np.array(timingList)
    coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, order)
    fit = np.poly1d(coefficients)

    plotChart(
        f"{title}\n {fit}", 
        xlabel, 
        ylabel,
        x,
        y,
        fit
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can treat log(n) and nlog(n) as first order polynomials where the x values is log(n) or nlog(n). That is, you take the log(n) or nlog(n) before fitting and use that as the input to polyfit. Here's an example for log(n):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Fake Data 
x = range(1,101)
y = 5 * np.log(x) + np.random.rand(len(x))

# Fit 
coefficients = np.polyfit(np.log(x),y,1) # Use log(x) as the input to polyfit.
fit = np.poly1d(coefficients) 

plt.plot(x,y,"o",label="data")
plt.plot(x,fit(np.log(x)),"--", label="fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you are using other functions that can't be simplified to polynomials you can use [curvefit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) from the scipy library.